# User Profile Sync Service Behavior

Tags: user-profile-service

I have created a synchronization connection to an AD that results in 100k accounts synchronized. If I change sync connection criteria (branches selected, or filters applied) so only 20k accounts match these criteria, what happens with the resulting 80k profiles already imported in SharePoint? Are they deleted on the following synchronization or they stay in the profile db until they are manually deleted?

Is it the same behaviour if I change 2 sync connections of type "Active Directory" to "Active Directory Logon Data" + "Active Directory Resource"?
Thanks

Comment: Please read this about the My Site cleanup job that will affect you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx

Comment: Looks like after changing the type of connection, the "extra" 80k accounts are ignored by the synchronization process, so they remain in the UPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will remain in profile db. As you have change sync criteria so next and further synch will happen on that basis with only 20k profiles. rest 80k profile will have no impact on this.